# How do I change my background on my MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro

On my MacBook Air, I accidentally somehow pasted a picture on Olaf on my screen and when I try to change it, it just goes into a black screen. I have tried changing the screen saver and it just doesn't work. Does anyone know what's wrong with my computer?

Comment: If you right click on your desktop and select "Change Desktop Background...) does that not work?

Comment: No it says that my background is a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I've found to do this is to simply right click on the desktop, which will open up a popup menu (*see screenshot below of popup menu*).

**NOTE:** Right clicking can either be a 2 finger click or a 2 finger tap (depending on how you have your gestures configured).

[image]

Then from here you can change the image.

[image]

Comment: @user3439894 - good call, I wrote that up when I was 1/2 way out the door this AM. Fixed, thanks for the heads up.